# repeated image of HERE map using Leaflet library

Tags: javascript, leaflet, heremaps

I'm trying to add an HERE map to Leaflet, but the result is as follow:

[image]

my javascript code is:

```
var defaultPoint = {
    lat : 44.6478300,
    lon : 10.9253900
};

function initMapLeaflet(apiKey, json) {
    try {
        map.remove();
    } catch (Exception) {
    }
    var coords = JSON.parse(json);
    var center;
    if (coords.lat != null && coords.lon != null) {
        center = coords;
    } else {
        center = defaultPoint;
    }
    map = L.map({$DIV_ID}, {
        center : [ center.lat, center.lon ],
        zoom : 10,
        layers : [ L.tileLayer('https://1.base.maps.ls.hereapi.com/maptile/2.1/maptile/newest/normal.day/13/4400/2686/256/png8?apiKey=' + apiKey) ],
        zoomControl : true
    });
    map.attributionControl.addAttribution('&copy; HERE 2019');
}
```

I tried to recover the whole world through URL but the only difference was the content of the image that was repeated.

Zoom in/out and drag work correctly but at the end of the previous events, the `<div>` shows the same repeated image again.

Comment: So why are using the numbers `13/4400/2686` in the `TileLayer`'s URL *template*? Do read https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#tilelayer

Comment: Thank you, I didn't understand that the URL could be kept generic